# Generating the list of edge weights for each vertex in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

The `igraph` function:

```
nn.list <- adjacent_vertices(g, V(g))
```

outputs a list of adjacent vertices for each vertex.

This is very useful. But now I need a similar list containing the edge weights.

For example, if vertex `600` has the follow adjacent vertices `597, 598, 599, 601` found from `nn.list[[600]]`, I now need a list where entry `600` gives the edge weights between vertex `600` and each of the adjacent vertices `597, 598, 599, 601`.

I can do this with a for loop - but it's slow. My network has about `10^4` nodes and `10^5` edges. I'm looking for a vectorized approach.  Is there a built in functions in `igraph` would help me do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)
g<-make_empty_graph(directed = F)

g<-add.vertices(g,c(10))

g<-add_edges(g,c(3,5))
g<-add_edges(g,c(4,5))
g<-set_edge_attr(graph = g,name="weight",index = E(g)[1],value = 0.3)
g<-set_edge_attr(graph = g,name="weight",index = E(g)[2],value = 10)


gedges<-E(g)
gweights <- E(g)$weight

as_adj(g)


 as_adj(g,attr="weight")

as_adj(g)
as_adj(g,attr="weight")
as_adj(g,attr="weight", edges = T,sparse = F)
```

If you want to retrieve a vector of ALL edges, use `E(g)`, if you want a vector of ALL weights use `E(g)$weight`

Then, as you seem to need an `adjacency matrix` you can use `as_adj` tweaking the params until you get all info you want to!

Comment: LocoGris Thank you!!